# missing : after property is ajax request

Tags: javascript

it is probably a duplicate in some way because many people are having the same error. I read through similar questions but I still do not understand why this script throws that error.

```js
<script>
$("#clientList").change(function (event) {
 $.ajax({
  url: "/LoadClients",
  data: { id = $("#clientList").val() },
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "html",
  success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) { }
 });
});
</script>
```

I am still pretty new to the whole JavaScript thing so thanks in advance for pointing me towards the light

Comment: `data: { id = $("#clientList").val() },` should be `data: { id : $("#clientList").val() },`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot perform `=` assignment in a JS object. You must use the `:` operator.

```
data: { id : $("#clientList").val() },
```

The colon `:` operator defines properties, while the equals `=` operator assigns value to a variable. Inside a JS object, properties are not variables, so you muse assign the property's value with the `:` operator.

Answer (score 2):

inside object `:` is used instead if `=`.

this

```
data: { id = $("#clientList").val() },
```

should be

```
data: { id: $("#clientList").val() },
```